# Re-draw transparent background on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with a transparent background.

After drawing some content, I want to erase part of it and go back to the transparent background.

Simply drawing on top of the content to be erased with

```
fillStyle = rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

does not do anything, since transparent on top of a color = color.

Is there a mode that sets subsequent drawings to "replace content at this position"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the clearRect function

```
context.clearRect(x, y, width, height)
```

see this http://jsfiddle.net/5g87J/

Comment: Same answer as above, but accepted because of the fiddle. Always nicer to have something to play around with.

Comment: i think we wrote it at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Your best (and probably only) option is `.clearRect(x, y, w, h)` to delete part of the canvas.